# Virtual Destructor - c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I defining the base class destuctor as "Virtual".
Eg:-

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        cout << "Calling ~Base()" << endl;
    }
};
```

And Also in derived class too for Example:
Eg:-

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        cout << "Calling ~Derived()" << endl;
    }
};
```

My question is how both destuctor's are gets called while deleting the pointer of the base class pointing to the derived class object.???????
thanks..,

Answer (score 1):

An instance of a class is built in memory as a "building" where the foundations are the highest classes in the hierarchy. Destrcutors are called in an order opposite to constructors.

Meaning:

> Sub-Sub-class -> Sub-Class ->Class

The destructors are always called. After you destruct a part of the object (sub-class) the class that it's derived from is destructed and so on.

The reason that you don't have to call a "super" destructor from your sub-class is that a destructor must always be called. Also, as opposed to constructor where you might not have a default constructor (which enforces you to explicitly call the super constructor), this is not the case in destructors. You always have one destructor with no args, so the compiler can always tell "which" destructor to call (as there are not that many options).

Comment: i didnt get clearly Avi... let me explain with examples.. thanks..